# Mod rewrite with multiple query strings

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm a complete n00b when it comes to regular expressions. I need these redirects:

(1)

```
www.mysite.com/bike.php?id=001&product=Product-Name&source=Source-Name
should become -> www.mysite.com/Source-Name/001-Product-Name
```

(2)

```
www.mysite.com/car.php?id=002&product=Product-Name&source=Source-Name
should become -> www.mysite.com/Source-Name/002-Product-Name
```

(3)

```
www.mysite.com/moto.php?id=005&product=Product-Name&source=Source-Name
should become -> www.mysite.com/Source-Name/005-Product-Name
```

(4)

```
www.mysite.com/stores.php?id=002&name=Store-Name
should become -> www.mysite.com/002-Store-Name
```

**Edit:** I should have clarified, there are 3 product pages, which should all redirect to the same format URL

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure you don't need them the other way around? Most people do.

Comment: This time you got lucky, but mostly when asking questions on the internet you can not expect other people to do your work. Other people are willing to help you, and it helps if you show that you have taken some effort to solve the problem. In your case, you could show us the RewriteRule you came up with. Even if it is totally wrong, you have shown that you tried it yourself.

Comment: @Iganacio - Heh, you're right.. That's why the regexs haven't been working. Again, noob :p
Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} www.mysite.com/(.+)/(\d+)-(.+)  /products.php?id=$2&product=$3&source=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} www.mysite.com/(\d+)-(.+)  /products.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

I think it work's well ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-(.+)$ /stores.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(\d+)-(.+)$ /products.php?id=$2&product=$3&source=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, how would I reverse those rules? Thanks :)

Comment: You mean that the user should enter and see the long & ugly URL and it has to be silently transformed in the short and clean one? It's the exact opposite of what everyone does: giving a visible "nice" URL and let the server handle the dirty stuff under the hood.

Comment: Eg. the browser shows "http://mysite.com/Source-Name/001-Product-Name" in the url bar, but the actual page is feeding from http://mysite.com/bike.php?id=001&product=Product-Name&source=Source-Name

Comment: That's exactly what the rules I wrote do :)

Comment: hmm.. doesn't seem to be working.. Would it matter if everything's in the /dev directory? eg. http://mysite.com/dev/products...

Comment: It's just redirecting to my homepage.

Comment: Well I wrote `/stores.php` assuming it was in the webroot, if that script is located elsewhere, update the path in the rule accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! Sorry to be a pain, this is my first time working with modrewrite. I tried "^(\d+)-(.+)$ /dev/stores.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]" and "dev/^(\d+)-(.+)$ /dev/stores.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]", both still redirect back to the root

Comment: Maybe you have other rewrite rules?